# open-closed sets problem for discrete math

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

how do we show that the only subsets of R that are both open and closed are R and Null set?

I understand how to show for R but not for the null set.

any help would be appreciate

Comment: Your second sentence does not make much sense. The set $\mathbb R$ is an open and closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Also, the empty set is an open and closed subset of $\mathbb R$. Ok so far? You are now supposed to show that there is no other subset of $\mathbb R$ that is both open and closed. This fact is often stated as “$\mathbb R$ is connected”, maybe that helps you look for a proof, there should be several on this site.

Comment: Could you help me to find the link? and thank you so much for correction

Answer (score 2):

**Proof**: Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be open and closed but such that $X\neq \mathbb{R},\emptyset$. Choose $a\in X$ and $b\not\in X$ and assume without loss of generality that $a<b$.

Let $c=\sup \{x\in X : x < b\}$ ($c$ is well-defined since $a\in X$).

***Exercise***: Prove that $c\in X$ and $c\not\in X$ and thus arrive at a contradiction.

Hope this helps and please let me know if you get stuck with the exercise.